# how many times a string is present in a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, count, cell

I have the array

`a={'2';'23';'231';'2312';'23121';'231213';'3';'31'}`

and the cell array

```
b={'2' '21' '' '' '' '' '';'3' '32' '' '' '' '' '';'2' '24' '242' '2423' '' '' '';'(34)' '(34)2' '' '' '' '' '';'4' '43' '432' '4323' '' '' '';'3' '32' '321' '3212' '32124' '321243' '';'3' '34' '343' '3432' '34323' '' '';'(34)' '(34)3' '' '' '' '' '';'2' '21' '212' '' '' '' '';'3' '32' '323' '' '' '' '';'4' '41' '413' '4132' '41321' '413213' '4132132';'3' '34' '342' '3423' '34232' '342321' '';'4' '42' '421' '4212' '42124' '' '';'4' '43' '432' '4324' '' '' '';'4' '43' '432' '4323' '43234' '' ''}
```

I want to know how many times the string in a are present in b

```
eg string '2' is present 3 times
   string '23' is present 0 times
   string '231' is present o times
   string '3' is present 5 times
```

it's the same for the all strings in a

I want like output an array with the number of times strings in a are presents in b, can you help me?

If the question is not clear, I try to explain better

Comment: I think [`strcmp`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) will do. try to code..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcmp(S1,S2)` returns 1 if S1 and S2 are the same. Use `find` to find which indices contain the string you are trying to find and then check the `length` of the returned vector. Finally, turn this into a string with `num2str`. Now you have the number of times a string is present in `b`.

Here's the code:

```
result = cell(length(a),1);
for k = 1:length(a)
    result{k} = sprintf('string ''%s'' is present %d times', a{k},  length(find(strcmp(b,a(k)))));
end
```

Result:

```
result = 

'string '2' is present 3 times'
'string '23' is present 0 times'
'string '231' is present 0 times'
'string '2312' is present 0 times'
'string '23121' is present 0 times'
'string '231213' is present 0 times'
'string '3' is present 5 times'
'string '31' is present 0 times'
```

Comment: Nice, `sprintf` might be more readable than using `[]` to concat the strings. Also if you do `result{k}=...` you can leave off the `{}` on the RHS.

Comment: I think ismember can do it without the loop, but this is a good answer.

Comment: @GameOfThrows, how would you call `ismember` to avoid the loop? That would probably be really nice.

Comment: you need to reshape b to a single column/row first `c = reshape(b,1,size(b,1)*size(b,2));` and then its just `[ia ic] = ismember(c,a)`

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the result to be honest, though it's intriguing. Please excuse my ignorance, would you care to explain? Perhaps in another forum if commenting is not suitable?